# Why was Captain Cold given the surname Snart?

Tags: dc, captain-cold

Captain Cold's name is Leonard Snart. Why was 'Snart' picked for his last name? In Norwegian, 'snart' means 'fast'.

Comment: _Snart_ means ‘soon’ in Norwegian at least ten times as often as it means ‘fast/quick’.

Comment: I believe the word is also used in Swedish. Sometimes when you hear either language spoken, it begins to sound like English.

Comment: Yes, it's used in both Swedish and Danish as well. It has both meanings in all three languages, and the ratio of how common the meanings are (‘soon’ perhaps 98% of the time, ‘quick/fast’ the last two) are approximately the same in all three as well.

Answer (score 5):

With the notable exception of Hartley Rathaway (the Pied Piper), none of the characters created by [John Broome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Characters_created_by_John_Broome) seem to have the sort of bizarrely [ironic names](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Mister_Freeze) so [heavily favored](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/The_Riddler) by other writers of the period.

- [Mirror Master](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirror_Master) = Sam Scudder
- [Doctor Polaris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Polaris) = Neal Emerson
- [Spellbinder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spellbinder_(DC_Comics)) = Delbert Billings
- [Sportsmaster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sportsmaster) = Lawrence Crock
- [Weather Wizard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weather_Wizard) = Mark Mardon

The best guess would be that the choice of the name *Snart* was intended to demonstrate the sheer *ordinariness* of his character, a janitor who chanced upon a gun with freezing powers.

Comment: Probably 'Snart' was picked for a Dickensian flavor to the character, like Uriah Heep. In the English language, many things that are considered at least somewhat repulsive start with the letters 'sn', like snake, snail, snot ...

Comment: @HowardMiller - It's really only Batman where we find the truly dumb ironic names. Edward Nigma? Really? C'mon.

Comment: I'm pretty sure those villains had their names retconned.

Comment: @HowardMiller - Can you give an example?